# How do I access the app running inside my minikube cluster from a different machine?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I am running `ghost` inside my minikube cluster via the following commands:

```
kubectl run ghost --image=ghost:0.9
kubectl expose deployments ghost --port=2368 --type=NodePort
```

Now, as my server has no frontend, I want to see the service in one of my browsers, preferably via ssh port forwarding.

I saw in a Github issue that once can do an ssh forwarding by executing the below command:

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L 3000:localhost:2368
```

However, I am unable to find an `id_rsa` file in the path. I find only the `config.json` file there.

So, is there a way I can generate the `id_rsa`, or some other way I can do the ssh port forwarding?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly, you want to reach the ghost welcome web page in your browser and you are not able or is it something else that you would like to achieve?

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue differently or maybe my solution worked for you? If indeed it solved your issue please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the ghost image got pulled, by using `kubectl get pods`, because I tried with 0.9 and couple of times I got `ImagePullBackOff`, `kubectl run ghost --image=ghost` works fine every time, but it pulls latest version.

For accessing Ghost from browser I was able to achieve it using:

`minikube service ghost
Opening Kubernetes service default/ghost in default browser...
And indeed it is available under: 'http://192.168.99.100:31187'`

If you want to reach it from different machine in the network you will need to play with ingress and ingress controllers. If that was your goal (this is why I asked question, because I was not sure) I can try to assist you with that, but also minikube is not the best solution for that, although it is possible.